# Dynamic Type Conversion

Tags: c#, dynamic, types

I have the following method

```
public static void SerializeToXMLFile(Object obj,Type type, string fileName)
{
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    ns.Add("", "");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fileName);

    serializer.Serialize(tw, obj, ns);
    tw.Close();
}
```

The problem is that notice in the line of code that obj will be serialized as an object.

**serializer.Serialize(tw, obj, ns);**

What I would prefer is that it is serlized as its relevant type for example:

**serializer.Serialize(tw, (type) obj, ns);**

How is this done? To get the type conversion to work from a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will be serialized as the appropriate type.

The `Serialize` method has a parameter type of `object`, so even if you *could* make this cast, it wouldn't do any good. It's not like it's a generic method which could use the compile-time type.

If you believe the relevant data isn't being persisted, please post a short but complete example to show this. It should work fine.

Comment: What a really good answer... and I gotta tell you, because I'm on a deadline I really appreachiate the quick response... thanks!